# jQuery/javascript: how to distinguish between different table rows of the same percentage selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, label

This fragment is created N times in a table row/cell *td* of a table in the html structure by inserting it in the DOM via javascript code:

```
    <div class="noselect">
        <div class="class_innerPercentage clearfix">
           <label for="up"></label>
             <input id="input" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="5"
               value="100" class="noselect" readonly="readonly">
             </input>
           <label for="down"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This insertion is done by something like:

```
$("#id_createNewRow").click(function () {
    $('#start_bottom_line').before('<tr><td>....
```

Finally I get something like:

[image: snippet of four rows of the percentage picker]

Additionally to the insertion in the DOM an event listener is installed for each new table row:

```
    $("label[for=down],label[for=up]").on("click", function (event) {
        $("#input").val(function (_, n) {
            return event.target.htmlFor === "up"
                ? +n < +this.max ? +n + 5 : n
                : +n > +this.min ? +n - 5 : n;
        }).trigger("arrow")
    });
```

When the referring arrow up/down button is clicked, there should just be an increase/decrease only for the actually clicked row in the table.

Presently just the first table row is increased / decreased.

How can I manage to increase/decrease the presently clicked row correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify it with data attributes and not using an id. The input is a sibling of the label.

```js
$("label[data-dir]").on("click", function(e) {  //select the labels and bind click
  
  var label = $(this),  //label
      dir = label.data("dir"),  //get step direction to increase or decrease
      input = label.siblings("input"),  //find the input that is a sibling of the label
      step = Number(input.attr("step")),  //Get the step, no need to hard code it in the JavaScript
      min = Number(input.attr("min")),
      max = Number(input.attr("max")),
      updatedVal = Number(input.val()) + (dir*step); //change the value with the step size
  
  if (updatedVal>max) updatedVal = max;
  else if (updatedVal<min) updatedVal = min;

  input.val( updatedVal );  
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="noselect">
  <div class="class_innerPercentage clearfix">
    <label for="input1" data-dir="-1">-</label>
    <input id="input1" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="100" class="noselect" readonly="readonly">
    <label for="input1" data-dir="1">+</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just a last question remains: what are the referring css equivalents for the arrow icons and the `%`? In the old variant it was: `label[for="up"]:nth-of-type(1):before {` and `label[for="down"]:before {` and `label[for="down"]:after {
    content: "%";`

Comment: Either use a class or the new data attributes [data-dir="-1"]

Answer (score 0):

You have several HTML issues:

First, note that the HTML `<input>` element does not have a closing tag. Remove `</input>`.

Also, the `type=number` is not supported in many browsers and will default back to a textbox that will not have any arrows to click on. [See here for browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number)

Additionally (and most importantly), if you are creating that same HTML snippet repeatedly, then you will wind up with each row containing an element with an `id` of `input`, so when your event handler goes looking for it, it will always stop on the first one it finds.

You need to make sure that each element that gets inserted gets a unique `id`.

After that is accomplished, the event handler can be changed to access the current row with this:

```
$(".class_innerPercentage").on("click", "label[for=down],label[for=up]" , function (event) {
    var theInput = this.parentNode.querySelector("input");
    $(theInput).val(function (_, n) {
        return event.target.htmlFor === "up"
            ? +n < +this.max ? +n + 5 : n
            : +n > +this.min ? +n - 5 : n;
    }).trigger("arrow")
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, `var theInput = this.querySelector("input");` is `null`, as `this` is equal to `<label for ="down"> ::before ..after </label>`

Comment: `this` is the label and the input is not a child of the label.

Comment: Use `this.parentNode.querySelector("input")` instead. It will query in its parent node

Comment: @ankitChaudhary : `this.parentNode.querySelector("input")` was helpful, thanks. Now there remains one additional  issue: If I have two rows, the event for row number one is processed twice. (row number two is processed only once, which is the desired functionality).

Comment: So you want event for row one should process just once

Comment: the solution for this topic was: 
before the `on("click"...` there must be a `off();`... otherwise every new row adds a new listener to the existing one(s).

Comment: @user2145488 Or, you could have just used `addEventListener()` and not JQuery at all to do the event binding.